# How to do a democracy pallet vote using Polkadot API in typescript

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

I am trying to do a democracy vote using the API.

First I am getting the balance of my account:

```
  const balance = (await api.query.system.account(my_account)).data.free;
```

```
  const voteConfig: Vote = new GenericVote(api.registry, {                                                                                                                           
    aye: true,                                                                                                                                                                      
    conviction: 'None',                                                                                                                                                              
  });                                                                                                                                                                                
  let vote: PalletDemocracyVoteAccountVote = { asStandard: { vote: voteConfig, balance: balance } };

  let txHash = await api.tx.democracy.vote(i, vote).signAndSend(payoutKey, (({ events = [], status }: any) => {
```

But I am getting the type error below:

```
/home/nochem/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:820
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
votebot.ts:102:48 - error TS2322: Type '{ vote: Vote; balance: u128; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly vote: Vote; readonly balance: u128; } & Struct<TypesDef<Codec>, { [x: string]: any; }, { [x: string]: string; }>'.
  Type '{ vote: Vote; balance: u128; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Struct<TypesDef<Codec>, { [x: string]: any; }, { [x: string]: string; }>': #private, defKeys, getT, isEmpty, and 25 more.

102   let vote: PalletDemocracyVoteAccountVote = { asStandard: { vote: voteConfig, balance: balance } };
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@polkadot/types-augment/lookup/types-substrate.d.ts:430:18
    430         readonly asStandard: {
                         ~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'asStandard' which is declared here on type 'PalletDemocracyVoteAccountVote'

    at createTSError (/home/nochem/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:820:12)
```

How can I compile the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`asStandard` is when you receive the object back. In that case the `is<Key>` and `as<Key>` helpers allow you to convert the received enum to the internal view of a specific field.

To construct it, it needs the key `Standard` for the enum, so you need -

`{ Standard: { vote: voteConfig, balance: balance } }`

The API would always create the types, so you never need to do it manually via `new`. In this case I would suggest -

```js
  let vote = { 
    Standard: {
      vote: {                                                                                                                           
        aye: true,                                                                                                                                                                      
        conviction: 'None',                                                                                                                                                              
      },
      balance: balance
    }
  };

  let unsub = await api.tx.democracy.vote(i, vote).signAndSend(payoutKey, ...);
```